# How to publish different menutype joomla on module position?

Tags: menu, navigation, joomla3.0

I am trying to remind how to use Joomla 3. Please let me know about how to publish different menu on top module position? I have checked up menutype and extensions->modules. Thanks..

Regards,
Maksym

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created a menu and you want to publish it on the top module position. For that you need to goto extensions->modules and then click on new tab there you will find menu so click on that 
[image]
and select which menu you want from dropdown list as given in image here
[image]
Then select on which pages you want that menu from the menu Assignment page.
next if its a horizontal top menu then under Advanced tab you will find an option
Menu Class Suffix add " nav-pills". You will get a bootstrap horizontal menu.